# REST route identifier other than 'id'

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have a resource 'users'. You can request information about a particular user via:

```
users/:id
```

where 'id' is a number. I also want to have the ability to query a user via their username. I am wondering what the route should be for enabling this functionality?

I was thinking of making id both username and id, but there's ambiguity because what if a user has a username with all numbers and that number matches another user's id.

So what I am asking is, what is the convention for handling this? Should it be:

```
usernames/:username
```

or `users/:username/username`

or something completely different?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought: The “users” space could be partitioned into two sub-spaces: “usernames” and “ids”.

Then, they can be accessed separately:

```
/users/usernames/:username
/users/ids/:id
```

The short-hand for the “ids” space could be just “/users/” and it would be accessed like:

```
/users/:id
```

Comment: Cool, that's a good idea. I will wait for more responses, if not i will accept this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would leave getting a user by id via the url route method:

```
/users/:id
```

and perform getting a user by username using the querystring:

```
/users?username=johndoe
```

Comment: This is conceptually the more "correct" approach. Getting a user via their ID is a lookup, where getting a user via their username is a *search* for a user based on a property, which could return partial matches.

Comment: Agreed. What am i thinking :-)